# Fluid .html() Ajax Refresh jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When I update the html of a div in jQuery (Ajax) : 
I have sometimes a whitescreen and then the content is refreshed and replaced by the previous html. (using the latest 2.x release)

Is their a way to avoid the whitescreen during the html replacement by jQuery?

In order to have a fluid refresh of content for an online shoutbox ?

Here's how I refresh the div of a shoutbox through jQuery :

```
var messageList = $(".content > ul");

$.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "shoutbox.php", data: "action=update"+panel+"&endroit="+endroit+"&clan_id="+clan_id+"&no_notif="+no_notif+"",
        timeout:5000,
        complete: function(data){

            var reponse_ajax = data.responseText;

            if(cache_texte != reponse_ajax){

                messageList.html(reponse_ajax);
                cache_texte = reponse_ajax;

            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could load the content in a new invisible div and then simply show the new div and hide the old one when the request completes.

Comment: Thanks! Well this issue from jQuery can be fixed by using innerHTML instead of .html() which empty the element by default.